# How to find area of Digital Elevation Model above/below a reference plane?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, dem, 3d-analyst

I am using ArcGIS10. I need to find the out the area which is below 5000 and above 5000 from the Digital Elevation Model which is available to me. How can I find out this ? My DEM ranges from 8848 to 309 m with the total area of 4100 sq.km.

Comment: If you have Spatial Analyst available, simply [compare the DEM to 5000](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Less_Than/009z000000m9000000/). The resulting grid will have an attribute table for the values 1 (below 5000) and 0 (above 5000). The [count] field in the table shows how many cells of each type there are. To obtain the areas of each, multiply the counts by the square of the cellsize.

Answer (score 2):

You will need a **3D Analyst** license, but from what I can see the **[Surface Volume](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Surface_Volume/00q900000027000000/)** tool provides the area above your **reference plane** as **Area 2D** in its output format.  You just need to provide its reference plane as being a **base_z** of 5,000 m.  The area below your reference plane will be ( 4,100 - Area 2D ) sq.m.

If this is too slow then @whuber's comment seems to provide a quicker solution:

> If you have **Spatial Analyst** available, simply [use Less Than to] **[compare the DEM to 5000](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Less_Than/009z000000m9000000/)**.
>   The resulting grid will have an attribute table for the values 1
>   (below 5000) and 0 (above 5000). The [count] field in the table shows
>   how many cells of each type there are. To obtain the areas of each,
>   multiply the counts by the square of the cellsize